# Uploading a file using HTML-FileUpload-Control - Access Denied

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iis-7.5

A click on my Import-Button executes the following JQuery-Code:

```
if ($("#fileUpload").val()) {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "Handler/Handler.ashx?op=Import",
                data: JSON.stringify(myData),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

`myData` is a JSON-object containing the filepath and some other values of HTML elements.

When this statement is reached...

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

...this is the exception that flies:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException - Access to the path XXX is denied.
```

I can solve this problem by giving full-control permissions to IUSER. However, this is not an option, since our endusers can't be expected to modify permissions everytime they want to upload a file. Is there another way that doesn't involve any enduser input?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can give the permission on fly, before using.

```
private bool GrantAccess(string filepath)
    {
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
        FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

        fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("IUSER", 
                      FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
                      AccessControlType.Allow));

        fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);
        return true;
    }
```

and after using-block

```
private bool RemoveAccess(string filepath)
    {
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
        FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

        fSecurity.AddAccessRule(
              new FileSystemAccessRule("IUSER", 
                      FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
                      AccessControlType.Deny));

        fInfo.SetAccessControl(fSecurity);
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Don't forget to include `using System.IO;`